# Difference between Task Manager's Processes and Details tabs

Tags: windows, process, cpu-usage, task-manager

In Windows' Task Manager we have 2 tabs that show process CPU usage: Processes and Details. Trying to find a hotspot in my developed software, I noticed that CPU usage differs there in a huge manner - say 3% CPU usage in Details, and 9% usage in Processes. What's the difference between those tabs? Which one is more accurate?